# How can I pass in a parameter to sed?

Tags: sed, find, search, parameter

To be more precise - how can I pass in a parameter to a program that then calls sed - how can I 'pass' that parameter along?

I have a file 'source_code.sc'.
I have a sed script "find_expect":

```
#n
/expect/{
=
p
}
```

that I invoke from inside a program that's looping through files with

```
sed -f find_expect.= source_code.sc
```

that print finds with their line numbers, such as

```
712
      expect(it).to be_true
```

However that search is hard-coded to search for "expect"
How can I change this so that the search text itself is also passed.
I am also looping through files with find so sed is currently invoked for many files.
For example, to search for 'blob' the program looping through files would invoke it with

```
sed -f find_expect.= "$file_from_loop" source_code.sc 'blob'
# with 'blob' being passed in from the main script
# which would be invoked with `./change_all.sh 'blob'
# I don't pass the file pattern in to this main call as I just
# recursively do all files (that match a pattern) from the current directory down
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to re-implement `grep`, there.
Instead of `sed` just use:

```
grep -n -- "$var" file
```

If `var` contains regex metacharacters that you want to match literally, supply the `-F` option to `grep`:

```
grep -nF -- "$var" file
```

where `var` contains your desired pattern.

From the `grep(1)` man page:

> **-n, --line-number**
>      Prefix  each  line of output with the 1-based line number within
>      its input file.  (-n is specified by POSIX.)

If you insist on using `sed`, you can make a function for that purpose:

```
notgrep (){
    if [ $# -ne 2 ];then
        echo "Usage: notgrep <pattern> <file>"
        exit 1
    end
    sed -n "/$1/{
        =
        p
    }" "$2"
}
```